# ROLL OUT IS UNCLICKABLE

Tags: android

APP CONTENT in left panel is displaying the msg "Due to adjusted work schedules at this time, we are currently experiencing longer than usual review times  Please expect review times of seven days or longer. " due to whch rollout option is unclickable

Comment: rollout is usually unclickable due to other parts of the console not being completed, such as uploading a privacy policy, or that the release would target 0 devices. Is this a new app, or are you trying to roll out an update?

Comment: this is new app , I have checked other parts are done.

Comment: If it's a new app, something will be missing.